# Class 'Album' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a problem in my controller(AlbumController) , I want to use one of my model(Album) in this controller but I got the error Class 'Album' not found
AlbumController.php :

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class AlbumController extends BaseController
{
public function getList()
{
$albums =  \Album::find(1);
return View::make('index')
->with('albums' , $albums);
}
}
```

Model : Album.php (App/Models/Album)

```
<?php
namespace App\Models\Album;
class Album extends Model
{
protected $table = 'albums' ;
protected $fillable = ['name' , 'description' , 'cover_image'] ;
public function Photos()
{
return $this->hasMany('images');
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting this error for namespace mismatch.There is 2 way to solve one is use your namespace in top of class

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use App\Models\Album;
class AlbumController extends BaseController
{
public function getList()
{
  $albums =  Album::find(1);
  return View::make('index')
 ->with('albums' , $albums);
}
}
```

another is use full namespace in method

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
class AlbumController extends BaseController
{
  public function getList()
  {
    $albums =  \App\Models\Album::find(1);
    return View::make('index')
    ->with('albums' , $albums);
  }
}
```

Comment: i got the error : Class 'App\Models\Album' not found

Comment: may you are using wrong namespace in your model class.May be it will namespace App\Models;

Comment: Yeah I was wrong in the namespace of my model , as you said it should be App\Model , Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You not use `use Album;` in yor controller
Try this

```
<?php  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use App\Album;
class AlbumController extends BaseController
{
  public function getList()
   {
     $albums =  Album::find(1);
     return View::make('index')
    ->with('albums' , $albums);
   }
}
```

Comment: i got the error : Class 'App\Models\Album' not found !